# python json.loads Unterminated string error

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have been following a chat bot tutorial and am stuck. I have included the exact step that I am on as a link at the bottom of this post in case you are curious what my code looks like (I was frustrated so I copied his code word for word).

During the execution of my code, it processes just over 26,000 lines before it throws the exception. My code can be found below. As you can see, I have tried various solutions including replacing /r and /n characters with nothing and adding the tag `strict=False` which should allow unterminated strings into the json, but that didn't work either.

```
with open('C:/Python34/stuff/chatbot/{}/RC_{}'.format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
    for row in f:
        row_counter += 1

        if row_counter > start_row:
            try:
                row = json.loads(row.replace('\n','').replace('\r',''), strict=False)

            ---------blah blah blah blah------------ 

            except Exception as e:
                print("RUH ROH " + str(e))
```

and the exact error message is below:

`RUH ROH Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 368 (char 367)`

link:
https://pythonprogramming.net/building-database-chatbot-deep-learning-python-tensorflow/

**EDIT:**

getting rid of the try catch gave me a little more information when the error is thrown and can be found below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/stuff/chatbot/chatbot_db2.py", line 103, in <module>
row = json.loads(row.replace('\n','').replace('\r',''), strict=False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 331, in loads
return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 368 (char 367)
```

**EDIT2:**

Following up on a comment, they suggested I print out the line that the exception was being thrown at. And it did shed some light.

`{"subreddit":"sydney","author_flair_text":null,"id":"cqugtij","gilded":0,"removal_reason":null,"downs":0,"archived":false,"created_utc":"1430439358","link_id":"t3_34e5fd","ups":6,"subreddit_id":"t5_2qkob","name":"t1_cqugtij","score_hidden":false,"author_flair_css_class":null,"parent_id":"t1_cqttsc3","controversiality":0,"score":6,"author":"SilverMeteor9798","body":"As state transport minister almost every press release from Gladys had something in there about how the liberals were \"getting on with the job\" and blaming Labor for something. It wasn't necessarily false, it just got tiresome after a while particular`

while a successful row will look like this:

`{"created_utc":"1430438400","ups":4,"subreddit_id":"t5_378oi","link_id":"t3_34di91","name":"t1_cqug90g","score_hidden":false,"author_flair_css_class":null,"author_flair_text":null,"subreddit":"soccer_jp","id":"cqug90g","removal_reason":null,"gilded":0,"downs":0,"archived":false,"author":"rx109","score":4,"retrieved_on":1432703079,"body":"\u304f\u305d\n\u8aad\u307f\u305f\u3044\u304c\u8cb7\u3063\u305f\u3089\u8ca0\u3051\u306a\u6c17\u304c\u3059\u308b\n\u56f3\u66f8\u9928\u306b\u51fa\u306d\u30fc\u304b\u306a","distinguished":null,"edited":false,"controversiality":0,"parent_id":"t3_34di91"}`

I am honestly more confused now but it does look like it ends in a `"}` for all of the objects. So either it isn't ending, or there is a character that can't be parsed?

**EDIT3 - SOLVED**

I assumed that the file was complete, but I guess there was an error downloading it and the file was cut off with an incomplete JSON Object as the last entry. So just deleting that entry solved the issue.

Thanks to everyone for the help

Comment: How about `except ... print(row.replace('\n','').replace('\r',''))`?  That should give an idea of what's throwing you off.

Comment: Do you have the input that it is failing on?

Comment: The JSON doc is 20000 lines long? Well, you obviously don't want to post it here. If you can strip it down to something small enough that produces the same error, that would be great, but there's a good chance you can't. So link to it in the repo or wherever it comes from, or at least tell us which generated pathname had the error. Also: If you can try a standalone `json.load` directly on that file (either in the REPL, or in a one-liner script) and verify that you get the same error, that would help.

Comment: @BradSolomon Just tried that and added it as an edit. It just looked like it just ended without closing. It looks like other "rows" that were successful included an author tag after the body, while where it is crashing there is nothing following the body because it terminates.

Comment: @cjnash There is no closing `}` in the row, so this row is not valid json for parser

Comment: @abarnert Yeah I am trying to add some 6GB of reddit comments to a DB for some chatbot, so posting the doc wouldn't be feasible. I will try the standard json.load and get back to you though.

Comment: @AntonKachurin is it just not printing that `}` because that is where it crashed? or is my file actually missing that `}` and then crashing? If so, is there any way for me to just discard that line if it doesn't include a closing bracket? Even further is there any way for me to just discard a row that has an exception in it? In my case I don't need every single line

Comment: It looks like it's actually like that in the file… but instead of guessing, open the file in a text editor, jump to that line, and see for sure.

Comment: @abarnert Didn't even think about that... But yup, I know what happened. It looks like this isn't the full file that should be downloaded, and it looks like it terminated early for some reason. It seems to have just cut off there and that is the end of the document.

Comment: Meanwhile: "One JSON document per line" is an odd format, because JSON allows newlines and other line terminators. You _can_ deal with this by encoding all line terminators, but there's always a risk that the encoding tool's notion of "line terminators" won't match the decoding tool's (not likely a problem for `\n`, but maybe for `\r`, and even more possible for, say, U+2029). That could be relevant here—maybe the line isn't actually truncated, it just ends in a non-`\n` line terminator that Python treats as a line terminator but the original code that created the file didn't.

Comment: Ah, a truncated file is a lot simpler. So now you get to figure out how to write the error handling so next time you get an incomplete file it won't be as much pain to debug. :)

Comment: @abarnert Yup, I deleted that line and re-ran my program and it worked. I guess I just assumed that the full file was downloaded and that there was an error in the middle, (because it should be WAY more than 26,000 lines) instead of an incomplete file. Thank you for your help and your side note about JSON documentation. I just am doing it this way because the file came with one per line.

Comment: In answer to your earlier question, It is very common in cases when data could get jumbled to throw out bad lines of data. You could just put an exception handler around the entire line. Often when people do that in production code they log the bad line of data to be looked at by a human to decide whether there is a bug or just bad data.

Comment: @cjnash Yeah, it's just one more thing you need to be aware of, and deal with in your error-handling strategy; you can't (usually) eliminate all problems like this in advance.

Comment: Meanwhile, since you ultimately solved this yourself, you might want to write up an answer and accept it. If you don't think the question and answer will be useful to anyone else, you can delete your question instead—but I think "trying to parse lines-of-JSON file that got truncated" is not a unique problem that nobody else will ever have.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah I added it as an edit to my question, but I guess I will just add it as an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained in EDIT2, I printed out the line that was giving me trouble, and saw that it did not end in a `}`, which every JSON Object should. I then went into the file, and checked the exact line that was giving me trouble by using a simple search, and I found that the line was not only truncated, but it was also the last line of my file as well.

There was definitely an error when I was either downloading or extracting this file, and it seemed to cut it short. This in turn threw the error that I got with no solution seeming to work.

**To anyone who is having this error and .replace() solutions are not working:**  try to look through your data and make sure that there is in fact something there to replace or edit. In my case there was a truncating error during the download or extraction which made such solutions impossible.

Big thanks to abarnert, Michael Robellard and Anton Kachurin

Answer (score 4):

I discovered the good guys at [Luminoso](https://luminoso.com/) have written a [Library](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to sort this kind of issue.

Apparently, *sometimes you might have to deal with text that comes out of other code. where the text has often passed through several different pieces of software, each with their own quirks, probably with Microsoft Office somewhere in the chain* --- [see this blog post](http://blog.conceptnet.io/posts/2012/fixing-common-unicode-mistakes-with-python-after-theyve-been-made/)

This is where [ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) comes to the rescue.

```
from ftfy import fix_text
import json
# text = some text source with a potential unicode problem
fixed_text = fix_text(text)
data = json.loads(fixed_text)
```